# How do I set values of Atlantis helm configurations

Tags: kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, atlantis

I am in trouble.

I want to try Atlantis which is an open-source automation tool for terraform. I would like to introduce a review-bot which reviews the result of the 'terraform plan'

I tried this document.
https://www.runatlantis.io/docs/deployment.html#kubernetes-helm-chart

I tried to deploy the Atlantis app to my EKS cluster.
But the result is like this.

```
$ helm install atlantis runatlantis/atlantis -f values.yaml      
NAME: atlantis
LAST DEPLOYED: Tue Jan 17 17:27:53 2023
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
NOTES:
1. Get the application URL by running these commands:
2. Atlantis will not start successfully unless at least one of the following sets of credentials are specified (see values.yaml for detailed usage):
  - github
  - githubApp
  - gitlab
  - bitbucket
```

I think something was wrong.
I even set the values.yaml file with my GitHub user, token, and secret.

But it's failed.
How can I solve it?

p.s. below yaml code is my values.yaml file.

```
  1 orgAllowlist: github.xxx.xxxxxxx.net/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/*
  2 github:
  3   user: dykim
  4   token: ghp_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  5   secret: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  6
  7 aws: {}
  8 serviceAccountSecrets:
  9 image:
 10   repository: ghcr.io/runatlantis/atlantis
 11   tag: v0.22.2
 12   pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
 13
 14 allowForkPRs: false
 15 allowDraftPRs: false
 16 hidePrevPlanComments: false
 17 disableApply: false
 18 disableApplyAll: false
 19 disableRepoLocking: false
 20 enableDiffMarkdownFormat: false
 21 commonLabels: {}
 22
 23 livenessProbe:
 24   enabled: true
 25   periodSeconds: 60
 26   initialDelaySeconds: 5
 27   timeoutSeconds: 5
 28   successThreshold: 1
 29   failureThreshold: 5
 30   scheme: HTTP
 31
 32 readinessProbe:
 33   enabled: true
 34   periodSeconds: 60
 35   initialDelaySeconds: 5
 36   timeoutSeconds: 5
 37   successThreshold: 1
 38   failureThreshold: 5
 39   scheme: HTTP
 40
 41 service:
 42   type: NodePort
 43   port: 80
 44   targetPort: 4141
 45   loadBalancerIP: null
 46
 47 podTemplate:
 48   annotations: {}
 49   labels: {}
 50
 51 statefulSet:
 52   annotations: {}
 53   labels: {}
 54   securityContext:
 55     fsGroup: 1000
 56     runAsUser: 100
 57     fsGroupChangePolicy: "OnRootMismatch"
 58   priorityClassName: ""
 59   updateStrategy: {}
 60   shareProcessNamespace: false
 61
 62 ingress:
 63   enabled: true
 64   ingressClassName:
 65   annotations: {}
 66   path: /*
 67   pathType: ImplementationSpecific
 68   host:
 69
 70   hosts:
 71   tls: []
 72   labels: {}
 73
 74 resources:
 75   requests:
 76     memory: 1Gi
 77     cpu: 100m
 78   limits:
 79     memory: 1Gi
 80     cpu: 100m
 81
 82 volumeClaim:
 83   enabled: true
 84   dataStorage: 5Gi
 85
 86 replicaCount: 1
 87
 88 test:
 89   enabled: true
 90   image: lachlanevenson/k8s-kubectl
 91   imageTag: v1.4.8-bash
 92
 93 nodeSelector: {}
 94
 95 tolerations: []
 96
 97 affinity: {}
 98
 99 serviceAccount:
100   create: true
101   mount: true
102   name:
103   annotations: {}
104
105 enableKubernetesBackend: false
106
107
108 environment: {}
109 environmentSecrets: []
110 environmentRaw: []
111 loadEnvFromSecrets: []
112 loadEnvFromConfigMaps: []
113 googleServiceAccountSecrets: []
114 extraVolumes: []
115 extraVolumeMounts: []
116 extraManifests: []
117
118 initContainers: []
119
120 extraArgs: []
121
122 extraContainers: []
123
124 containerSecurityContext: {}
125
126 servicemonitor:
127   enabled: false
128
129 podMonitor:
130   enabled: false
131   interval: "30s"
132
133 redis: {}
134 lifecycle: {}
```

Comment: Can you share your values.yaml? (mask your credentials)

Comment: I shared it. Please help.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. Have you been able to fix it?